# Generic typeguard factory

Tags: typescript, generics

I created the following function factory which should create type guard for given class.

```js
interface Constructable<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function instanceOf<T>(_class: Constructable<T>) {
  return (obj): obj is T => obj instanceof _class;
}
```

I tested it on the following `getDogs` function and it works as expected (return type is Dog[])

```js
class Animal { }
class Dog extends Animal { }
const animals: Animal[] = [];

function getDogs() {
  return animals.filter(instanceOf(Dog));
}

const dogs1 = getDogs(); // type of dogs1 is Dog[]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with generic function `getAnimalsOfType` (return type is Animal[] instead of Dog[])

```js
function getAnimalsOfType<T extends Constructable<Animal>>(animalType: T) {
  return animals.filter(instanceOf(animalType))
}

const dogs2 = getAnimalsOfType(Dog); // type of dogs2 is Animal[]
```

What is wrong with my `instanceOf` / `getAnimalsOfType` implementation? Thanks in advance.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rzswyg

Comment: You will have a better time with type inference if your signature looks like `function getAnimalsOfType<T extends Animal>(animalType: Constructable<T>)` instead.

Comment: Oh, changed it and works fine, thanks. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?